# finger command to only show username

Tags: linux, bash

Iam fairly new here, and looking to learn more about bash programming.

So first I need some help with the finger command.
When I use just "finger" thats what I get as output, obviously with some data sets.

```
Login    Name   Tty   Idle   Login Time   Where
```

What I want, is that I adapt the finger command so it only outputs the "Name" with its associated data sets, like that:

```
Name
...
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
finger | awk '{print $2}'
```

Edit: New approach using a combination of `awk` and `cut` that's somewhat more robust to arbitrarily formatted names.

```
#!/bin/bash
#parse_finger.sh

#Read first line from stdin
IFS='$\n' read -r line

#Count the number of chars until 'Name'
str=$(echo "$line" | awk -F "Name" '{print $1}')
start=${#str}
start=$((start+1))

#Count the number of chars until 'Tty'
str=$(echo "$line" | awk -F "Tty" '{print $1}')
stop=${#str}
stop=$((stop-1))

#Print out the 'Name' header
echo "$line" | cut -c $start-$stop

#Read in the rest of our lines and print the cols we care about
while IFS='$\n' read -r line; do
  echo "$line" | cut -c $start-$stop
done
```

Run it with `finger | parse_finger.sh`

Comment: Yea that helped, sadly than, if "Name" has 2 parameters like a persons name, that will only take the first parameter so the first name, and if I add $3 to get the second name, I also get the 3rd parameter from the header (Tty), can I somehow cut that out aswell?